# Use Authorize attribute on custom EmployeeRoles table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using code-first approach with Entity Framework. I want to create a many-to-many relationship between my `Employee` and `AspNetRoles` tables to assign roles to my employees.

The thing that concerns me is that if I use `[Authorize]` will my role from custom `EmployeeRoles` table be usable to .Net as it uses `AspNetUserRoles` table to navigate which user has which role?

When a user becomes an employee, he is still to be found in the `Users` table.

I don't really know where `[Authorize]` can read the role of an user and I'm guessing it's the table `AspNEtUserRoles` and I want to do the same thing for my `Employee` table.

[image: My database]

Comment: .NET doesn't *use AspNetUserRoles*. Rather, it takes your `IPrincipal` and calls `IsInRole`. How this is evaluated, totally depends on the implementation, in particular, how your `IPrincipal` is initialized when a user logs in. It's a common practice to read roles from your own tables. To answer your question, though, you'd have to show how you create your `IPrincipal`s.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't configure my own `IPricipal`. I am using MVC template with Individaul User Accounts.

Comment: You will have to dig deeper. If the template uses the AspNet Identity, you'll need a custom implementation of the role service.